# Azure service principal unable to assign permissions to resource groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-group

I am trying to build a azure web app to create a azure resource group and assign contributor permission for a specific user. I am using a powershell script to do this. when i run it in my local it does what it supposed to do. where as when i execute it on azure web app it throws the following error.

The service principal has owner permission on the subscription also it has the directory permission.

```
#Login to Azure using Service Principal
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal  -Credential $SPcred -TenantId "XXXXX-xxxx-xxxxxxx"

#Create resource group
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $Name -Location $Location -Force 


if((Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $Name).ProvisioningState = "Succeeded")
{

    New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $Name -SignInName XXXXXX -RoleDefinitionName Contributor
}
```

**Error Message:**

> The provided information does not map to an AD object id azure

Comment: just a silly question, `$SPcred` isnt empty? Web App is in the same tenant?

Comment: @4c74356b41 $spcred is not empty and webapp is in the same tenant

Comment: Is the user in the same tenant with the service principal that you login?

Comment: @JoyWang yes he is

Comment: If you change the `-SignInName XXXXXX` to `-ObjectId <Guid>`, will it work?

Comment: @JoyWang tried it didn't work same error msg

Comment: did you install azure powershell on your own on the webapp? try updating it?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Could you please provide a link or any guidelines of how to do it

Comment: As I know, web app seems not support powershell, how do you run the script? may be you mean web job?

Comment: What is the value of "xxxxxx" when you use the parameter `-SignInName`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use [Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0) to assign directory role to your service principal.

You could choose the specific directory role that you need, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles).

**Note:** You need to [install azure ad powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) first.

In this case, you could try to assign Application Administrator role to your service principal.

```html
# Fetch role instance
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}

# If role instance does not exist, instantiate it based on the role template
if ($role -eq $null) {
    # Instantiate an instance of the role template
    $roleTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}
    Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $roleTemplate.ObjectId

    # Fetch role
    $role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}
}

# Add the SP to role
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId  -RefObjectId <your SP ObjectID>
```